# Linq on TableCellCollection - C#

Tags: c#, linq

```
void foo (TableCellCollection bar)
{
  bar.Cast<TableCellCollection>().Where(a...
}
```

On the code above, the lambda '`a`' is still a `TableCellCollection` rather than a `TableCell`, can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you've *told* it that it should be `TableCellCollection` with your `Cast` call. If you want to cast each element to `TableCell`, that's the type argument you should give:

```
bar.Cast<TableCell>().Where(a...
```

Answer (score 1):

Further to Jon's answer your code would cause a cast exception at runtime.  The Cast method works on `IEnumerable` collections not `IEnumerable<t>`.  It would act as if you were doing the below:

```
IEnumerable EnumerableCells = bar;

foreach (object cell in EnumerableCells)
{
    TableCellCollection newCell = (TableCellCollection)cell;// this line would throw a cast exception
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this useful

```
var eta = e.Row.Cells;

eta.Cast<TableCell>().Where(a => a.Text == "Ind_Origen").Select(a => a.Text = "Origin").FirstOrDefault();
```

I use Linq to query the collection looking for a string and then change it. Its usefull if you are filling a gridview  and want to change the headers.